# Created laravel symlink on webserver still can't access the file without app/public

Tags: php, laravel

The project is running fine on local but on web server (running on sub domain) when I created symlink using `php artisan storage:link` or even `ln -s full_path/storage/app/public full_path/public/storage` through ssh, the symlink got created but I still can't access images inside my storage/app/public without **"app/public"**
eg: I can access http://xyz.abc.com/storage/app/public/35/conversions/retro1-thumb.jpg
but I can't access http://xyz.abc.com/storage/35/conversions/retro1-thumb.jpg

What I have already tried:

1. Deleted storage and ran `php artisan storage:link` - no help
2. Updated htaccess to follow symlink in root and public - no help
3. Run `php artisan config:clear` , `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan cache:clear` - no help
4. Updated config/filesystem.php with real path as storage and url - no help
5. Approached host support - no help
6. Did extensive google search - no help

Here's my config/filesystems.php disk conf-

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],
```

Hope it can be resolved.

Comment: Can you post your config file? You shouldn't be able to access files through the /storage/app/public path at all, that directory is not supposed to be directly accessible. That's why the symlink is necessary in the first place.

Comment: @AlecJoy You mean config/app.php ?

Comment: No, config/filesystems.php, particularly the public disc portion

Comment: @AlecJoy Updated the answer with filesystems.php disc conf

Comment: Where is your webroot pointed in your nginx or apache config? Something isn't right here, you should not be able to directly access the /storage/app folder in the browser. It's a level up from the public folder. If that folder is accessible, so are all your php files

Answer (score 3):

try the following:

1.) config/filesystems.php change root

2.) in public folder , remove storege folder and run php artisan storage:link

3.) Check if symbolic link is enabled in your server

Comment: Tried all, worked none.
Yes, symlink is enabled, how else can ```php artisan storage:link``` would have worked ?

Comment: there are alternate ways as well but doing the above steps should solve the issue if done correctly